# Paper-fab partially hides behind app-toolbar

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, app-elements

I want to import an element that contains a `paper-fab` and have the `paper-fab` overlap the seam between the `app-header` element and the imported element. (In this case, I'm calling the imported element a `fab-element`). In other words, I simply want the `paper-fab` to "float" (as advertised and like it's supposed to).

What I expect it to look like:

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qagudomowa/1/edit?html,output)

[image]

What it actually looks like:

[image]

1. FAB inside `app-toolbar`. (works) [Click here for jsBin](http://jsbin.com/celumequza/1/edit?html,output).
2. FAB outside `app-toolbar` but inside `app-header`. (works) [Click here for jsBin](http://jsbin.com/liqogucusi/1/edit?html,output).
3. FAB outside `app-header` and inside `main-content`. (fails) [Click here for jsBin](http://jsbin.com/depijoboci/1/edit?html,output).

I need to use the `app-header-layout` element and import the `fab-element` inside the `main content` section. As the above 3 jsBins show, that last combination seems to break the element (causing the top half of the `paper-fab` to hide underneath the `app-toolbar`).

How do I get the entire `paper-fab` to float over the `app-toolbar` while using the `fab-element` inside the `main content` section of the `app-header-layout`?

Or does this potentially expose a possible bug in `app-header-layout` element itself?

### Edit

***z-index (on `paper-fab`) has no effect.***

Notice the last example has the `z-index` increased to `99999`. It still seems to have no effect on the output.

### Edit 2

***z-index (on parent element) has no effect.***

Also, setting the `z-index` on the parent element `fab-element` also has no impact on the result.

### Edit 3

I wonder if what's happening with the `z-index` [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39803097/1640892) (read the comments) is related?

Comment: This seems like a bug. [So unless new information comes in, I will raise this as an issue here for now](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/issues/328).

Comment: Per @robodna on [Polymer Slack Site](http://slack.polymer.com): i think it has to do with app-header-layout forcing itself to the front with an !important somewhere, but I don't recall as I came across this very issue a while back...and maybe how the z-index of the children get scoped as well... even if you set z-index to 9999 on a child element, it won't appear in front some elements that are z-index 1, depending on how they are nested... that was the issue... the content is nested as a child and the header was higher up in the tree

Comment: Per @rob: does the fab need to live inside of that element? could it be outside of the entire layout and just position fixed?  https://jsbin.com/taruqiw/2/edit?html,output ...
the reason I say this is because if you put it inside the layout, I think you may need to force the `app-header` to `z-index: 0` to make the button overlap, but then all text in the layout overlaps as well when you scroll the page

Comment: Per @robodna: it looks like I may have set the following style on the app-header:
       `app-header {
       @apply(--layout-fixed-top);
           z-index: 1;
       --app-header-shadow: {
            box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            height: 10px;
            bottom: -10px;
        };
       }`

Comment: i don't see that it changed anything in the result... http://jsbin.com/sajawaledu/1/edit?html,output ... do you have a bin that proves it works?

Comment: Same thing here with a paper-fab sitting inside a paper-dialog. I am trying to position it on the upper right of the paper-dialog so that it stretches half-width outside of the paper-dialog, but this way all parts of the paper-fab that live outside of the paper-dialog box get shoved beneath the dialog backdrop, which has a z-index of 102. Giving paper-fab a z-index of 103 doesn't solve the problem, so the issue must be with paper-fab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @robodna on [Polymer Slack Site](http://polymer.slack.com) provides the following answer:

Set `z-index:2!important` on `#contentContainer`.
[See this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mitegigose/edit?html,output).

http://jsbin.com/mitegigose/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html" rel="import">
  <link href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-fab/paper-fab.html" rel="import">

</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="fab-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-fab {
        position: absolute;
        right: 40px;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 99999;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-fab icon="add"></paper-fab>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: "fab-element",
        properties: {},
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    app-toolbar {
      color: white;
      background-color: #3F51B5;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    app-header-layout ::content #contentContainer {
      z-index: 2!important;
    }
    fab-element {
      z-index: 99999;
    }
  </style>

  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header fixed condenses effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <div main-title>App name</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>
    <div>
      main content
      <fab-element></fab-element>
    </div>
  </app-header-layout>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {},
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```