# Polymer 1.x: paper-dialog modal appears behind app-header-layout

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, plunker, app-elements

I want to put a sub-element (child) inside an `app-header-layout`. The sub-element contains a `paper-dialog modal`. When I open the modal I expect to see the dialog box appear in *front* of the backdrop. Instead, the dialog appears *behind* the backdrop.

[image: Modal appears behind backdrop]

How do I get the modal dialog to appear in front of the backdrop? Or is this perhaps a newly discovered bug in the `app-drawer-layout` or `app-header-layout` elements?

[Here is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjPHGqkt8vvDbFdF4CNn?p=preview). ... http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjPHGqkt8vvDbFdF4CNn?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="x-app.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-app></x-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

x-app.html

```
<link href="content-el.html" rel="import">

<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">

<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<link href="app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html" rel="import">
<link href="app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html" rel="import">
<link href="app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html" rel="import">
<link href="app-layout/app-header/app-header.html" rel="import">
<link href="app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html" rel="import">

<link href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" rel="import">
<link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-app">

<template>

  <style></style>

  <app-drawer-layout>
    <app-drawer>
      drawer-content
    </app-drawer>
    <app-header-layout>
      <app-header>
        <app-toolbar>
          <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
          <div main-title>MyNewApp</div>
        </app-toolbar>
      </app-header>

      <content-el></content-el>

    </app-header-layout>
  </app-drawer-layout>

</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-app',
      properties: {},
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>
```

content-el.html

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<link href="paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="content-el">

  <template>
    <button on-tap="show">Click to show dialog</button>
    <paper-dialog id="dialog" modal>
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <div>Dialog body</div>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function(){
      Polymer({
        is: 'content-el',
        properties: {},
        show: function() {
          this.$.dialog.open();
        },
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: Weird - I downloaded the plunk and ran it locally with chrome dev tools.  The overlay had a z-index of 102 and the dialog box a z-index of 103, yet was still behind the overlay.

Comment: @akc42 the reason behind that is `z-index:0` of `app-header-layout` and `#contentContainer` (parents of paper-dialog).

Comment: @a1626: [Could all this be potentially related to this SO question as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39502060/1640892)? ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/39502060/1640892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known (see [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/109) and [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/issues/295) github issue) but unfortunately not very well documented limitations of the [iron-overlay-behavior](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-overlay-behavior), that is used by `paper-dialog`:

> You must ensure no element has a stacking context with a higher
>   z-index than its parent stacking context. You should place this
>   element as a child of  whenever possible.

One workaround is to move the `paper-dialog` outside of the `content-el` and also outside of the`app-header-layout` (either into the `index.html` or as a direct child of your root `my-app` element). You can fire an event (i.e. `open-dialog` and handle that in your root element).